# How the errors of the measured quantities of an adiabatic Hamiltonian are inversely proportional to the square root of the number of measurements?

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information, physics

I am going through the paper, [Solving the graph-isomorphism problem with a quantum annealer](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.042310), by Hen et. al. In the last line of the second paragraph of the second column of page 2, it says,

> Since errors of the various measured quantities are inversely
>   proportional to the square root of the number of measurements, this
>   number will be determined from the needed resolution.

I would like to know the reference of the statement that - **errors of the various measured quantities are inversely proportional to the square root of the number of measurements**.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't speak to this specific application, but usually such statements can just come from tail bounds like Chernoff or Hoeffding.

Let $X \in [0,1]$; let $\bar{X}$ be the average of $n$ independent draws of $X$.
For a given "margin of error" $\epsilon$, let $\delta = \Pr[|\bar{X}-\mathbb{E}X| > \epsilon]$. As usually stated, Hoeffding implies that $\delta \leq 2e^{-2n \epsilon^2}$, but often more useful is the restatement $\epsilon \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \frac{\ln{\frac{2}{\delta}}}{2}}$.